# Cannot understand 'functions as arguments' recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, sml, ml

I'm taking a functional programming languages course and I'm having difficulty understanding recursion within the context of 'functions as arguments'

```ml
fun n_times(f , n , x) = 
    if n=0
    then x
    else f (n_times(f , n - 1 , x))

fun double x = x+x;

val x1 = n_times(double , 4 , 7);

the value of x1 = 112
```

This doubles 'x' 'n' times so 7 doubled 4 times = 112

I can understand simpler recursion patterns such as adding numbers in a list, or 'power of' functions but I fail to understand how this function 'n_times' evaluates by calling itself ? Can provide an explanation of how this function works ?

I've tagged with scala as I'm taking this course to improve my understanding of scala (along with functional programming) and I think this is a common pattern so may be able to provide advice ?

Comment: I guess it seems too obvious to me. Try the rewriting approach (maybe with `n` of 3 instead of 4) in which you rewrite the top level call and each recursive call with the result of substituting the actual parameter values into the references to the formal parameters in the body of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `n_times` has a base case when `n = 0` and an inductive case otherwise. You recurse on the inductive case until terminating on the base case.

Here is an illustrative trace:

```ml
   n_times(double, 4, 7)
~> double (n_times(double, 3, 7)) (* n = 4 > 0, inductive case *)
~> double (double (n_times(double, 2, 7))) (* n = 3 > 0, inductive case *)
~> double (double (double (n_times(double, 1, 7)))) (* n = 2 > 0, inductive case *)
~> double (double (double (double (n_times(double, 0, 7))))) (* n = 1 > 0, inductive case *)
~> double (double (double (double 7))) (* n = 0, base case *)
~> double (double (double 14)) 
~> double (double 28)
~> double 56
~> 112
```

Answer (score 6):

If `n` is 0, `x` is returned.

Otherwise, `f (n_times(f , n - 1 , x))` is returned.

What does `n_times` do? It takes the result of calling `f` with `x`, `n` times, or equivalently: calls `f` with the result of `n_times(f, n - 1, x)` (calling `f` `n-1` times on `x`).

Note by calling `f` i mean for example:

calling `f` 3 times: `f(f(f(x)))`

calling `f` 2 times: `f(f(x))`

Answer (score 4):

Just expand by hand.  I'm going to call `n_times` `nx` to save space.

The core operation is

```
nx(f, n, x) -> f( nx(f, n-1, x))
```

terminating with

```
nx(f, 0, x) -> x
```

So, of course,

```
nx(f, 1, x) -> f( nx(f, 0, x) ) -> f( x )
nx(f, 2, x) -> f( nx(f, 1, x) ) -> f( f( x ) )
...
nx(f, n, x) -> f( nx(f,n-1,x) ) -> f( f( ... f( x ) ... ) )
```

Comment: This was my suggestion. I was just too slothful to do it for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same recursion thinking what you know already, just mixed with another concept: higher order functions.

n_times gets a function (f) as a parameter, so n_times is a higher order function, which in turn is capable to apply this f function in his body. In effect that is his job, apply f n times to x.

So how you apply f n times to x? Well, if you applied n-1 times

```
n_times(f , n - 1 , x)
```

, then you apply once more.

```
f (n_times(f , n - 1 , x))
```

You have to stop the recursion, as usual, that is the n=0 case with x.